# Android Java : Error when submit form(post) on Webview

Tags: java, android, webview, submit, csrf

I want to load in webview this page, https://pkfieur.gares.io/pk2geo/, and past data in "Ligne" and "PK" and click on "Rechercher".

Past data isn't a problem, but the submit yes.

Here the html:

```
<form id="form-id" method="post">
  <div id="the_post">...</div>
  <input type="submit" value="Rechercher">
</form>
```

And the code :

```
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("https://pkfieur.gares.io/pk2geo/");

go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()     {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   web.loadUrl("javascript: document.getElementById('id_ligne').value ='" +  ligne.getText() + "';" 
+ "document.getElementById('id_pk').value ='" + pk.getText() + "';" 
+ "document.getElementById('form-id').submit();");
 }
```

});

When my edit text is ready, i click on my button GO (in my app) and the webview telling me this :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpQnB.jpg)

Can someone help me, i know it is maybe a cookie, or debugging problem, but i try so much without find solution.

**EDIT** : When we quick in research, we have a latitude & longitude : I just want to take this data, and for this i use Webiew, ( not custom tabs because it will be open a new tabs ..)and after i set WebView Visibility to false !

If you have better solution like http or other, i dont know.. :/

Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding edit from TS, TS should probably use an API for that and then use Retrofit or something else in order to call the API.

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Edit2: I extracted the calls from the website. Use this endpoint in your Retrofit instance or API call adapter in order to call the API. Look below for the request method & API endpoint.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://pkfieur.gares.io/data_pk2geo/?ligne=XXXX&pk=XXXX
```

Where XXXX are the query strings (which you would normally type in the fields on the website), you should change those when calling the API.

Comment: Ty, look my EDIT !

Comment: I see. Well in that case, I would recommend using API calls for that. It's bad-practice to do it your way when an API would be exactly suited for your type of implementation.

Comment: Seriusly man, thank u. Simple ! I have tested similare approche but with id_ligne&id_pk not just ligne&pk .... BEST APPROCH